# Flutter Memory Leak on IOS Due to Large Amount of Variables Assignment

Tags: flutter

My flutter app is working perfectly on Android, but in IOS it crashes on both real devices in simulatorrs due to memory leakage as below.

```
flutter ios Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=1450 MB, unused=0x0).
```

after some troubleshooting, this is happening in a streambuider connecting to firestore where I get many configuration paramaters for my app. they are 60 paramater assignment like the below:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('AppConfigsCollection')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Container();
    } else {
    if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
    return Container();
    } else {
    variable1 = snapshot
                  .data!.docs[0]['Config_variable1']
                  .toString();
    variable2 = snapshot
                  .data!.docs[0]['Config_variable2']
                  .toString();
    .
    .
    .

    variable60 = snapshot
                  .data!.docs[0]['Config_variable60']
                  .toString();
    return Widget();}}}),
```

The part works fine on Android, but on IOS it can only assign up to 50 variable, more than this it crashes and generates the error.

Why is that? and how 60 strings can consume all the app memory? what is the best solution?
considering that all these variables are crutial for the app and can't reduce them.

full run output for reference:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: Z89H7WAJDD
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           308.0s
Installing and launching...
10.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:

to ensure proper integration.
10.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.10.3.0 started
10.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application
10.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application
10.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
10.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
10.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60988/AWnfx2cL1rU=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone...
flutter: LangInit
flutter: en
flutter: AppConfig
[GETX] Instance "MyLocaleController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "MyLocaleController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
* thread #10, name = 'io.flutter.1.ui', stop reason = EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=1450 MB, unused=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x000000010886924c Flutter`dart::Object::HandleImpl(dart::Zone*, dart::ObjectPtr, long) + 116
Flutter`dart::Object::HandleImpl:
->  0x10886924c <+116>: str    x20, [x9, #0x18]
    0x108869250 <+120>: tbnz   w20, #0x0, 0x10886925c    ; <+132>
    0x108869254 <+124>: mov    w8, #0x3a
    0x108869258 <+128>: b      0x108869278               ; <+160>
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device
```

Comment: Try assigning this `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('AppConfigsCollection').snapshots()` to a variable in initState or when declaring the variable and then use the variable as the value for the stream property. Every time the build method that contains StreamBuilder runs (which can be very often), you are reinitialising the database call.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. But the memory leakage isn’t coming from the repetition of widget build. It actually happens from the numbers of variables assignment from the first time, and I don’t know why, it is working very smoothly on Android.

Comment: Ok. As a matter of interest why do you store your config variables as a collection rather than one document with 60 fields? Your code suggests there are always 60, so pretty static.

Comment: Where should I store this document? I thought it would be better to have a separate collection for configs. However it ended after all with only one doc as you mentioned.

Comment: You would have a single document in the collection, I guess,, but I don't understand why you are reading a single document as a stream of document snapshots in a streambuilder, which is intended to support additional documents being created. If you have a single doc with all the config variables then you just read that doc once and store it's content. Not need for the [0].

Comment: Aha. Understood. First I need it to be a stream builder, so if I changed any value, it automatically do the change on the app. And you are correct, better to make it DocumentSnapshot rather than QuerySnapshot. I tried this today but didn’t help with the memory issue. Any idea why the variables assignment causing memory issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252087/discussion-between-grahamd-and-mark-nugromentry).

Comment: Tried the chat, can't send from my phone for some reason.

Comment: I am not sure why the memory issue I'm afraid. Given this is config, are you really sure you need real time response from the app or could it happily wait until the next time it is opened? Basically, I would be looking to simplify the read of the config vars as much as possible. I would be using a simple get() to retrieve the single doc and then assign it's content to a custom object in order to easily reference the config values. In that way I would be more confident that it is not using unnecessary memory. See this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_2